# Load a page via HTTP and make an AJAX request via HTTPS afterwards using CSRF-Token

Tags: csrf, https

I have the following scenario:

- A page is loaded via HTTP
- The user fills out a form and submits its contents via HTTPS
- The craft CSRF prevention is enabled, so the previousy generated CSRF-Token is submitted along with the form
- Craft responds with a HTTP 400, because the Token is not valid for the request being send over HTTPS

Is there a way to use Crafts CSRF prevention feature in this scenaria? So say for example tell Craft to generate the token for an expected HTTPS request?

Regards,
Clemens

Answer (score 1):

Completely untested, but try setting the recently added [useSecureCookies](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#useSecureCookies) setting to `false` and see if that works.